# keep objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I store objects in an array so that I can call a method for each object in a loop.

How I would like the result to be:

```
[[obj1, obj2],[obj3, obj4]].foreach((firstObj, secondObj) => {
   firstobj.search();
   secondObj.search()
})
```

And the result will be as follows:

> Iteration 1:  obj1.search(); obj2.search();
>
> iteration 2: obj3.search(); obj4.search();

Any advice is welcome

Comment: I suggest reading [some documentation for the `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Comment: You can add to square brackets to destructure the arguments instead `[[obj1, obj2],[obj3, obj4]].forEach(([firstObj, secondObj]) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the argument list to "unpack" the pairs to 2 free variables:

```
[[obj1, obj2], [obj3, obj4]].forEach(([o1, o2]) => {
   o1.search();
   o2.search();
});
```

This is equivalent to doing (and indeed, [this is what Babel compiles the above to](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=NrD2CMCsEYBoAIKQEwF0FigZgUgLKqgHQBmoATgKICGAxgBYAUjYciaAlPALwB88AbwBQ8UaGhEAzgFNq5Bow4BuEWORTZ8psqEBfZUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.16.9&externalPlugins=babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator%406.24.1&assumptions=%7B%7D))

```
[
  [obj1, obj2],
  [obj3, obj4]
].forEach((_ref) => {
  let [o1, o2] = _ref;
  o1.search();
  o2.search();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack your array into two separate variables in the callback arguments like this.

```
[[obj1, obj2],[obj3, obj4]].forEach([firstObj, secondOb] => {
    firstobj.search();
    secondObj.search()
})
```

Or if you don't know the size of each nested array you can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten your array into one then execute your function in a forEach.

```
[[obj1, obj2],[obj3, obj4]].flat().forEach(obj => {
    obj.search();
})
```